# Possible to run snort without modifiers?

Tags: attacks, ids, snort

Is there anyway (e.g some command line argument) with which we can tell snort to run and perform detection but without caring for the rule modifiers if there are any ?

e.g

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"PROTOCOL-TELNET bsd exploit client finishing"; flow:to_server,established; dsize:>200; content:"|FF F6 FF F6 FF FB 08 FF F6|"; depth:50; offset:200; rawbytes; metadata:ruleset community, service telnet; reference:bugtraq,3064; reference:cve,2001-0554; reference:nessus,10709; classtype:successful-admin; sid:1253; rev:23;)
```

For the above rule, I would like snort not to care about content modifiers, like "depth" and "offset". I can delete these modifiers manually but that will take a lot of time considering thousands of rules.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you'd want to? Those are there to ensure a rule actually matches the traffic it's looking for.

Comment: Because I want to generate test cases for each rule and it is not convenient to emulate the conditions mentioned in modifiers. All I am worried about is the actual signature.